# Basic and Digest Access Authentication with Java

Tags: security, spring, authentication, basic-authentication, http-digest

I am developing a web application with Spring. I have read about basic and digest authentication fundamentals. However how can I implement it with Java, is there any code example or is there any framework does it form me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/AlternateAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup) with commons http client library...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Spring…

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) implements these things, and its [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html) is a good place to start reading about it.